# Get the returned promise from $animateCss in angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, animation, ng-animate

How can I retrieve the promise from this animation from any location in my code?

```
angular.module('module', ['ngAnimate'])
    .animation('.notification', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
        return {
            enter : function(element, done) {
                return $animateCss(element, {
                    // Animation options
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

The animation is triggered succesfully using something like an `ng-if` on a dom element.

```
<div class="notification" ng-if="notifier.active">...</div>
```

How can I get the promise without manually invoking the enter method?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service:

```
animationServices.service('animationServices', function ($q){
      this.animateCss = function(){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
               $animateCss(element, {
               // Animation options
               deferred.resolve(whatever);
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    });
```

And then register your service and call it simply from wherever:

```
    animationServices.animateCss().then(function(data){

       //some code
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new promise and make it available immediately using the `promise` property in the returned object, but don't resolve it *until* you call the enter function and the animation is finished. [More information here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
    var deferredAnimation = $q.defer();
    return {
        enter: function(element, done) {
            $animateCss(element, {
                // Animation options
            }).then(function() {
                deferredAnimation.resolve();
            });
        },
        promise: deferredAnimation.promise
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that'd be necessary as the returned promise from the `enter` method would be good enough. What doesn't seem possible is to retrieve the result or any other properties from the returned object of a `.animate`. I think I will have to do it manually within a directives link.

Comment: You cannot use the promise from enter, because that will also execute the animation. Or am I misunderstanding "*How can I get the promise without manually invoking the enter method?*"?

Comment: Maybe the question isn't worded that well. As it turns out you can't get the promise at all from a `.animation` as it is invoked only when a class is added / removed / moved. I wanted the animation to execute when changing the class but to also retrieve the promise from it. It turns out this isn't possible so I've built the animation using `$animate` wrapping `$animateCss` within the `xClass` methods. This lets me get the animation promise with `$animate.addClass(...)`. Thanks for your answer though I appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't mind I'll edit your answer to show how I managed it and can then give you some accreditation at least for trying to help me out?

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but it's probably better to add and accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
var animation = $animateCss(element, {
    // Animation options
});
var promise = animation.start().getPromise();
```

-- EDIT --

Remember that if you want the JS animation to still function you need to do:

```
var animator = animation.start();
var promise = animator.getPromise();
return animator;
```